# Android management api - Setting default apps in work profile

Tags: android-management-api

I have a requirement to make Chrome the default browser in the work profile created with Android Management API. Currently the chrome app gets installed in the profile automatically on work profile provisioning. But it is not made the default app.
I have looked though the https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies document but have not come across any such settings.
Any guidance on how to achieve this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Persistent preferred activity management](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VTYyTmREvpCYU_4BDg2n5WdgMEhawjRJ0BqMDGttSqo/edit?usp=sharing) can be used to set up your default browser but unfortunately there is a related internal bug with the said functionality